# Understanding the differences in these list selectors

Tags: css

I am working with a stylesheet that has 2 different rules:

```
#main_navigation ul li{ ... }
```

and:

```
#main_navigation li{ ... }
```

I'm not clear on how to interpret the difference. In my reasoning - 'li' can't exist independent of either a ***ul*** or an ***ol***.

Is the above saying 'use the first for all items in an unordered list' but use the second for any list item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

The first says "apply the following rules to all `li` which are descendants of a `ul` which in turn is a descendant of an element with id `main_navigation`."

The second says "apply the following rules to all `li` which are descendants of an element with id `main_navigation`."

Answer (score 2):

Yep. The second rule matchs `<li>` elements in both ordered `<ol>` and unordered `<ul>` lists. The first is more specific and only matches unordered list items.

Comment: +1 Best explanation of the "difference" between the two selectors.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If the `<li>` lies under `<ul>` it will match the first rule as well as the second.

Answer (score 0):

The first line of code says "apply this style to list items of unordered lists within the div with id of main_navigation"

The second line of code says "apply this style to list items of any type of list within the div with id of main_navigation"